# Spotify Web API 使用時に405エラーが発生する

Tags: google-apps-script, webapi

何が原因で405エラーが出ているのかわからないので、詳しい原因と、解決法を教えてください。
https://api.spotify.com/v1/search に対して歌手名で曲の検索をかけてみましたが、何も結果が返ってきませんでした。getResponseCode()をしてみたところ405と出たので、一通りのHTTPメソッドを試してみましたが、何を入力しても405が返ってくるだけでした。
アクセストークンはプログラム起動の度にリフレッシュトークンから取得する方式で、見た限りではscopesにも問題はなさそうでした。
どうかよろしくお願いいたします。
コードの詳細と、実行時のログの画像を張り付けておきます。

以下、コードです。

```
function getMusic() {//歌手名で検索をかけ上位１０個分の曲名を引っ張ってくる
  var payload = {
    "q": "ピノキオピー",
    "type": "track",
    "market": "JP",
    "limit": 10,
  };
  var accessToken = getAccessToken();
  console.log(accessToken);
  var options = {
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "method":"POST",//HTTPメソッドの種類
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
  };
  console.log(payload);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(payload));
  var artist = "ピノキオピー";
  //おそらくここでresに何も入っていない
  //パラメタの指定が間違っている？
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search";, options);
  var contentText = res.getContentText();
  var responseCode = res.getResponseCode();
  //ここでエラー
  console.log(responseCode);//エラーコード405
  console.log(contentText);//空
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res));//Syntax error

}

function getAccessToken() {//リフレッシュトークンからアクセストークン取得
  var refreshToken = "XXX";
  var clientId = "XXX";
  var clientSecret = "XXX";
  var basicAuthorization = Utilities.base64Encode(clientId + ":" + clientSecret);
  var headers = { "Authorization": "Basic " + basicAuthorization };
  var payload = {
    "grant_type": "refresh_token",
    "refresh_token": refreshToken,
  };
  var options = {
    "payload": payload,
    "headers": headers,
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";, options);
  console.log(JSON.parse(res));
  return JSON.parse(res)["access_token"];
}
```

[image: ブロック引用]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpotifyのWeb APIの公式ドキュメントを見ますと、"Search for Item"は、GETメソッドでリクエストをする必要があり、表示されている`payload`の値は、query parameterとして使用する必要があるようです。[Ref](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search) この場合、`getMusic()`を次のように修正するのはいかがでしょうか。

```js
function getMusic() {
  var payload = {
    "q": "ピノキオピー",
    "type": "track",
    "market": "JP",
    "limit": 10,
  };
  var accessToken = getAccessToken();
  console.log(accessToken);


  // --- 下記を修正しました。
  var options = {
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
  };
  var queryParameter = Object.entries(payload).map(([k, v]) => `${k}=${encodeURIComponent(v)}`).join("&");
  var url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?${queryParameter}`;
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  // ---


  var contentText = res.getContentText();
  var responseCode = res.getResponseCode();
  console.log(responseCode);
  console.log(contentText);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
}
```

#### Note:

- ここでは、`payload`の値やアクセストークンはAPIを使用するための有効な値であると仮定しています。